# name of node when you know an attribute using path?

Tags: xpath

I have some XML where I know an attribute (in my case an ID#). I can get the node I'm looking for using //*[@id='v6969482']. But isn't there a way to tell me the name of this id? (I'm trying to have it return 'title' or , in my case. I know it has to do with using name(), but I can't seem to get the right syntax of returning the name when I have the id attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<topic id="v6969481">
  <title id="v6969482">CR - ASE | AXX2500>Engines>EIOA>EIOAn>GMACn>Ingress</title>
  <body id="v6969483">
    <p id="v6969484">
      <table id="v6153057" frame="all" colsep="1" rowsep="1">
        <desc id="v6049915">Global ingress attributes for EIOA engine GMAC ports.</desc>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the name of the parent node of the attribute, its parent element:

```
name(//*[@id='v6969482'])
```

Comment: I was close, I just couldn't quite get it. Thanks!